# Programatically Shows a Pop Yes No Pop up inside a code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

Good Day Every one,

Can you help me produce a code to produce pop up window like return confirm? the thing is it should be inside a method not after a click.

```
if (a == "1")
{
    //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "messagebox", "<script>$(document).ready( function() { csscody.confirm('<br/><h1>  Confirmation</h1><br/>       We have currently existing Details for that Upload Proceed?<br/>',{onComplete: function(e){if(e){process();__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCommitSaving','');}}});return false;});</script>", false);
    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "messagebox", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Continue Uploading?.');</script>");
    // here a pop up message should appear if he press yes he will do the procedure if no the program will cancel the procedure  
 // the other one is just an alert with OK button not having Yes or no
}
```

i tried the code with // but its not working it just passes by it in debug mode.
im sorry but i have a very minimal understanding about javascripts. so please help me any reading materials for my future reference would be ideal but a code with explanation would be better Thank you so much!

**Edit

Honestly Speaking i really do not know why it is not working in debug mode it just passes in that statement without any pop up box that appears, im really sorry if i do not know about javascripts that's why im asking help to enlighten me, also to find a way around about this problem.

Comment: any comment would be ideal also. not just down voting

Comment: Edit your question to explain what "its not working" means.

Comment: sorry @Blorgbeard im not good about javascripts im just new in programming in asp. im really sorry.

Comment: Are you asking for C# or Javascript?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead im doing it in asp.net with c#  any method would suffice as long as i can understand it.

Comment: You don't have to be good at programming to clearly explain your problem. We can't see your screen, or read your mind. I wasn't asking *why* it's not working, I was asking what *exactly* is not working. What happens exactly, and what did you expect? A well-explained question will get you more answers quicker!

Comment: @Blorgbeard thank you for your advice, your a good person :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

you should only do it on if you want to add the script on page first load and not after you postback and you can use javascript confirm

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
"ButtonClickScript", "confirm('Please select date within the same month and year')", true);
```

Comment: This answer works sir, but how can i implement that if i click yes he would do the following procedures if no he will cancel/exit the procedure?

Comment: what procedure show more

Comment: please see my edit in the code above.

Comment: you want to tiger a potback event

Comment: can you tell me the logic and i will do the coding im really sorry and thank you so much.

Comment: you need to use your other part you just showed in the button click event